# Do glassfish application running on port 80

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4

I have a java application running on glassfish 4.1, the url to access the system is a sobdomain, eg

> subdomain.mydomain.com:8060/ProjectName

I wanted to make it work without entering the port

> (subdomain.mydomain.com/ProjectName)

.

I've tried to change the port of the http-listener-1 to 80, but after that the domain of glassfish does not boot anymore.

Any idea how to run without the user having to enter the port?

Comment: Are getting any error? The problem might be there is a process already using that port or you dont have permission to use that port.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons why you should not use Glassfish listening to 80 directly.

Firstly port 80 is reserved, it's not easy to make a non special user to open 80 on a *nix environment.

It's common and recommended to install apache or nginx on port 80 and use mod_proxy_ajp to connect Apache or nginx to Glassfish through port 8009

[Oracle wiki](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/Running+GlassFish+V3+with+Apache+httpd+via+mod_proxy_ajp)